# Using if operators && || in the same condition

Tags: javascript, if-statement, input, operators, conditional-statements

I have this form

```
<form class="form" method="post">
<input type="text" id="input_what" holder="what" />
<input type="text" id="input_where" holder="where" />
<input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

and this script to prevent submitting the form

```
$('.form').submit(function(e) {
var what = $('#input_what').val();
var where = $('#input_where').val()
if ( what == "what" || what ==""  &&  where == "where" || where == "") {
   e.preventDefault();
   console.log('prevented empty search');
   return false;
}     
});
```

I know that my condition doesn't work, but i need it to work like this

```
 IF (what == "what" OR what == "") AND (where == "where" OR where == "")
```

have a look at this fiddle to understand why  http://jsfiddle.net/pK35e/

the placeholder-script i´m using, needs me to not submit the form for the cases above
using `placeholder="attribute"` is no solution for me, so can anyone give me a hint how to set this if-condition ?

Comment: I didn't understand why you don't use parens in your code.

Comment: If you were spoilt by VB coding style. :)

Answer (score 4):

Uses parenthesis just like in the textual description you made :

```
if (( what == "what" || what =="")  &&  (where == "where" || where == "")) {
```

Side remark : You might be interested, for future versions as it's not supported by IE9-, by the [placeholder attribute](http://diveintohtml5.info/forms.html) which will make this simpler.

Comment: wow these were the most correct answers in 30 seconds i ever realized adding to SO.  thanks I didn´t know that works that simple

Comment: yeah i hate the placeholder attribute, because i dont like that the text is not hidden on focus and that every browser has it´s own way to render it, this is why i made this little placeholder script wich has my desired look and feel even in IE 6 :D... thanks anyway to your informative link too

Comment: Why don't you use a placeholder polyfill?  There are so many out there, I can't imagine why anyone would roll their own.  I usually use this one: https://github.com/ginader/HTML5-placeholder-polyfill

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
if ( (what == "what" || what =="")  &&  (where == "where" || where == ""))
```

Answer (score 2):

```
IF ((what == "what" ||what == "") &&(where == "where" ||where == ""))
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe you need some parenthesis in order to get what you want:

```
if ( (what == "what" || what =="")  &&  (where == "where" || where == ""))
```

This means that both

```
(what == "what" || what =="")
```

and

```
(where == "where" || where == "")
```

has to return true in order for the code within your if statement to be executed. This is actually quite close to your textual example.

--

Just for the understanding of all of this. Your old code would look like this with parenthesis:

```
if ( (what == "what") || (what ==""  &&  where == "where") || (where == "")) {
```

Where again, just one of these would have to return true.

Answer (score 2):

Use parens. The `&&` operator has a higher precedence     than the `||` operator.

```
if ((what == "what" || what =="") && (where == "where" || where == ""))
```

http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_of_operations